# maven-shade-plugin: How to copy classes under BOOT-INF in the root of the generated jar?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-shade-plugin

So I have a spring boot application and I am creating a fat jar with the maven-shade-plugin like below

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>id1</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <manifestEntries>
                    <Multi-Release>true</Multi-Release>
                  </manifestEntries>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

The thing is that I want the resulting jar to contain the classes under BOOT-INF both in the BOOT-INF directory and also be at the root of the jar.

Is there a way to do that? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you using `maven-shade-plugin` instead of the more specific `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to create the fat jar?

Comment: Don't. Ditch the shade plugin and use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` which already creates a fat and runnable jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am also using `spring-boot-maven-plugin`. The thing is, I want to jave a jar that can be executed as a spring boot app like  `java -jar my-app.jar` but also have a duplicate of all my classes in the root of the jar like when creating a classic jar without spring boot. The reason is I want to submit the same jar to spark and it needs to find my user-defined classes at the root of the jar. So the thing is that spring boot places my classes under `BOOT-INF/classes` but I also want them in the root of the jar. Is that possible? To have the same class files in two places inside the jar?

Comment: Don't. The Spring Boot plugin can create 2 artifacts for you one with the dependencies and one without, which is what you should use.

Comment: @M.Deinum What if I need only one jar that has everything the way I described. Is there a way to do that? I would have to do major changes in my app otherwise which I would prefer not to except if there was really 100% no other workaround

Comment: WHy would you need major changes in your app? It is 3 lines of xml for the spring boot plugin, why would that be a massive change?

Comment: `<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
      </plugin>`
I already have this and it doesn't do what I want. Which 3 lines of xml code are you talking about?